# Plots won't show up in qtconsole

Tags: python, matplotlib, qtconsole

I have read tons of questions on this, but I am still baffled. I'm running Anaconda in Scientific Linux. I launche a console a type `ipython qtconsole`.

My `script.py` is something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
plt.show()
```

I type `run script.py` from the qtconsole, and the program just sits and does nothing. What am I doing wrong? I have been using the qtconsole for running my scripts, maybe it's better for really being interactive with and I should be running my scripts some other way?

Any general advice on workflow would be very helpful here. When should I use `python script.py`, when should I use `ipython script.py`, and when should I use the qtconsole, etc...?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a [Magic Function](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html) problem

More specifically [%matplotlib](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib). `%matplotlib inline` will show it within the browser, or you can replace `inline` with whatever you feel better for your use.